# Segmentation fault error: How to access my sha256 function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to get the hash value by putting the message value in the sha256 function. But I get a segmentation fault error.

This is my main function.

```
int main() {
    unsigned char *digest;
    unsigned char *message = "fsd";
    unsigned int len=3;
    sha256(message, len, digest);
    printf("%s",digest);    }
```

Below is sha256 function.

```
void sha256(const unsigned char *message, unsigned int len,
        unsigned char *digest);
```

How should I access the function so that it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: perhaps allocate some memory for `digest` ?

Comment: @jjiji, With `unsigned char *digest; .... sha256(message, len, digest);`, code is passing an uninitialized `digest` to `sha256`.

Comment: You don't just not allocate memory for `digest` but you also do not set it to `NULL` allowing anyone to detect that you did not allocate memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`digest` needs to point somewhere. In your code `digest` is just an uninitialized poibter that points nowhere.

```
int main() {
    unsigned char digest[some_length];  // the digest will be put here

    unsigned char *message = "fsd";
    unsigned int len=3;
    sha256(message, len, digest);
    printf("%s",digest);
}
```

where `some_length` is the length needed for the SHA256 digest, refer to the documentation of the `sha256` function.

Also depending on what exactly `sha256` does (you didn0't provide the code nor any documentation), `printf("%s",digest);` won't work because `digest` might contain unprintable characters.

Comment: Thank you for answer. sha256 is a function that creates a hash value of a message of length len and stores it in the digest. I want to check what hash value is stored in the digest, is there any way to print the digest?

Comment: @jiji yes, there is a way. It depends on what **exactly** `sha256` does. Your description in your comment is not accurate enough.

Comment: I want to check the hash string in the digest array using printf. I don't know how to format it to print the digest.

Comment: @jiji you still didn't andwer my question. What does the `sha256` do? Does it put the _raw bytes_ of the hash into the buffer pointed by `digest` or does it put the hexadecimal representation of the hash? If it's the raw bytes you can't use `printf("%s",digest);`, you have print each indivisual byte of the digest with something like `printf("%02x ", thebyte)`.